# MySQL Get Total Query from Unknown Columns at Runtime

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total of the unknown columns at runtime from a table.

Here's the source_table:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | Name       | Unknown 1 | Unknown 2 | Unknown 3 | Unknown 4 | Unknown 5 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | abc        |     10.00 |     18.00 |      5.00 |     21.00 |      6.00 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | ghq        |     22.00 |     14.00 |     12.00 |     11.00 |     23.00 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | xyz        |     35.00 |      8.00 |     16.00 |      7.00 |      4.00 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And here's the desired result_table I am trying to achieve:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| MyColumns |   Total   |
+-----------+-----------+
| Unknown 1 |     67.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Unknown 2 |     40.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Unknown 3 |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Unknown 4 |     39.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Unknown 5 |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I already figured out the query for the unknown column (1st field) above. But, I am having difficulty how to get the total column (2nd field) with my attempt code below:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydb' 
AND   `TABLE_NAME`   = 'source_table'
AND   `COLUMN_NAME` NOT LIKE 'ID'
AND   `COLUMN_NAME` NOT LIKE 'Name';
```

I will appreciate any help here to get me the total column (2nd field) using my code above.

**UPDATE 1:** @Akina answer result_table — CORRECTED BY QUOTING HERE
`''',COLUMN_NAME, '''`.

```
+-----------+-----------+
| MyColumns |   Total   |
+-----------+-----------+
|     10.00 |     67.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
|     18.00 |     40.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
|      5.00 |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
|     21.00 |     39.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
|      6.00 |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Build full query text based on obtained column names list using common string functions, then execute this text using prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'SELECT ''',
                             COLUMN_NAME,
                             ''' Columns, SUM(`',
                             COLUMN_NAME,
                             '`) Total FROM mydb.source_table' )
                     SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n' )
INTO @sql
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
  AND TABLE_NAME   = 'source_table'
  AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3040f272b3c86f9bf6ec070ee33fc18b)

For debugginig purposes - execute only SELECT query removing INTO clause firstly (also you may edit to `SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n'` - the query text will be more clear for to view), check that built query text is correct synthactically, then execute it and check that its output is correct too. If not - edit.

Possible problem source - the column name may be a reserved word or may concain spaces or another problematic chars. In such case you must add quoting backticks to wrapping string literals in CONCAT.

---

PS. Code edited, all mentioned editions (and database name - for to make the code CurrentDB-independent) added into.

PPS. Database and table names (and even skipped names list) may be converted to parameters if needed, making the code more universal...

Comment: Okay I will try this now. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the columns reserved name to MyColumns in my question.

Comment: Please see my update above for the result of this answer: Your answer gave me the correct totals but I am wondering why the MyColumns are getting the 1st row data instead. I compared it with what I did for the first column query in my question and I see no difference with you. Why your answer is giving me different result — still figuring out.

Comment: If I removed the this `',COLUMN_NAME,' MyColumns,` I am getting the Total correctly. But if I removed the `, SUM(',COLUMN_NAME,') Total`, I am getting all the data of the rows in the MyColumns. So weird. Something somewhere is missing.

Comment: @RickyBelmont True - quoting error. Editing... Done.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you so much @Akina! I really appreciate it!

Comment: One last thing if you don't mind. I tried to insert the ORDER BY here `FROM project_x.canvass_prices ORDER BY Total`, `'\nUNION ALL\n' ORDER BY 'Total'`, `'\nUNION ALL\n ORDER BY Total'` but it is not working. Since this is a concat approach, I cannot just simply put the ORDER BY like a normal query.

Comment: I also tried this one just before prepared statement:
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Container', 'Size')
ORDER BY 'Total' ASC;, but no avail.

Comment: I tried it here:
`ORDER BY 'Total' DESC SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n'`
It changes a bit the column but not the right descending order.

Comment: I have created a separate question for this sorting case here —https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200469/how-to-sort-this-mysql-query

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_bad_table;

CREATE TABLE my_bad_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,Name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,Unknown1 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,Unknown2 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,Unknown3 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,Unknown4 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,Unknown5 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_bad_table VALUES
(1,'abc',10.00,18.00, 5.00,21.00, 6.00),
(2,'ghq',22.00,14.00,12.00,11.00,23.00),
(3,'xyz',35.00, 8.00,16.00, 7.00, 4.00);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_good_table;
CREATE TABLE my_good_table AS
SELECT id bad_table_id
     , '1'+0 unknown
     , unknown1 score
  FROM my_bad_table 
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , '2'+0
     , unknown2
  FROM my_bad_table 
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , '3'+0 
     , unknown3
  FROM my_bad_table 
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , '4'+0 
     , unknown4
  FROM my_bad_table 
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , '5'+0 
     , unknown5
  FROM my_bad_table;


ALTER TABLE my_good_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(bad_table_id,unknown);
ALTER TABLE my_good_table ADD INDEX(score);
ALTER TABLE my_bad_table DROP COLUMN unknown1;
ALTER TABLE my_bad_table DROP COLUMN unknown2;
ALTER TABLE my_bad_table DROP COLUMN unknown3;
ALTER TABLE my_bad_table DROP COLUMN unknown4;
ALTER TABLE my_bad_table DROP COLUMN unknown5;
```

Query:

```
SELECT unknown
     , SUM(score) total
  FROM my_good_table
 GROUP
    BY unknown
 ORDER
    BY unknown;

+---------+-------+
| unknown | total |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | 67.00 |
|       2 | 40.00 |
|       3 | 33.00 |
|       4 | 39.00 |
|       5 | 33.00 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: As I understand the task, the column names are unknown really, not equal to `unknownX`.

Comment: @Akina You're probably right, but there's just no sensible reason why a column's name would be unknown. And anyway, this (or something like it) is how the table should most likely be structured, regardless of the column names.

Comment: Thank you for this @Strawberry. But, the unknown columns are variably created at runtime. Meaning, it can be of any column name at runtime. Moreover, forgot to mention, the number of that unknown columns can be any number as well though in my example I have shown 5 unknown columns only.

Comment: @RickyBelmont You're only endorsing the argument for restructuring the table as described above.