# How to Sort this MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, dynamic-sql

I am trying to insert the ORDER BY in this query to sort the Total column:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ''', COLUMN_NAME,''' MyColumns, SUM(`', COLUMN_NAME,'`) Total FROM mydb.source_table') SEPARATOR '\n UNION ALL \n')
INTO @sql
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
  AND TABLE_NAME   = 'source_table'
  AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

With the following result:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| MyColumns |   Total   |
+-----------+-----------+
| ABC       |     67.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| DEF       |     40.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| GHI       |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| JKL       |     39.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
| MNO       |     33.00 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Here's what I have tried so far but no luck:

```
1. mydb.source_table ORDER BY Total
2. SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n' ORDER BY 'Total' ASC
3. SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n ORDER BY Total' ASC
4. AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'Name') ORDER BY 'Total' ASC;
5. ORDER BY 'Total' ASC SEPARATOR '\nUNION ALL\n'
```

Comment: try removing the ' ; ' after the ASC

Comment: You're referring to no. 4 of my tries, I tried but it returns syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        'SELECT ''', COLUMN_NAME,''' MyColumns, SUM(`', COLUMN_NAME,'`) Total FROM mydb.source_table' 
        SEPARATOR '\n UNION ALL \n'
    ),
    '\nORDER BY Total DESC'
)
INTO @sql
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
    AND TABLE_NAME   = 'source_table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'Name');
```

Rationale: the `ORDER BY` clause should go *after* all `UNION ALL` subqueries - so it needs to be outside of the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, in an outer `CONCAT()`.

Also please note that you don't need `CONCAT()` *within* `GROUP_CONCAT()`: MySQL does that by default already.

Comment: No syntax error but at runtime it returns this error —
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: @RickyBelmont: I don't think this error comes from the changes I suggested...

Comment: Thank you @GMB. I missed something when I copied it. But now it works fine and I got what I want. Have a great day ahead!