# Sort Columns by Column_Totals through Alter Table or Select Query in MySQL at Runtime

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, dynamic-programming, alter-table, information-schema

I want to alter or generate Select Query of the `Source_Table` below at runtime by getting the column total (sum) first then sort according to its result:

`Source_Table`:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | Name       | Field_1   | Field_2   | Field_3   | Field_4   | Field_5   |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | abc        |        10 |        18 |         5 |        21 |         6 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | ghq        |        22 |        14 |        12 |        11 |        23 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | xyz        |        35 |         8 |        16 |         7 |         4 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The `Result_Table` I am looking at is:

```
             |--------------- sorted fields based on total --------------|

+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Name       | Field_5    | Field_3  | Field_4   | Field_2    | Field_1  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| abc        |         4 |         5 |        21 |        18 |        10 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ghq        |        23 |        12 |        11 |        14 |        22 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| xyz        |         4 |        16 |         7 |         8 |        35 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Total      |        31 |        33 |        39 |        40 |        67 | --> get column sum and sort from lowest to highest
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am not so sure if this is possible with MySQL as I am not able to find good reference in the internet for this case. But I will try..

Comment: I'm suggesting to not to do that. Even if this can be done, it will break the table's schema everytime you perform this.

Comment: @BonifaciusSarumpaet Another option I am looking is doing it at SELECT LEVEL QUERY. No need to alter the source_table. I will now edit my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583349/is-it-possible-to-sort-the-order-in-which-columns-are-returned-in-a-mysql-select Here, I find the answer you can check on them.

Comment: Regular query cannot return the rowset with dynamic (changeable) structure. The task may be solved using stored procedure with dynamic SQL. But I recommend you to perform column re-ordering on the client level. All needed data (both `Total` row and `column rank`) may be calculated in a query.

Comment: @Akina Actually, I forgot to mention here that the column names are dynamic (generated at runtime). That is the reason why I cannot do this at the client level. This is still related with my [previously raised question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188924/13810710) that you gave. The stored procedure (create table for get total and sorting) you gave will be used to figure-out the answer to this question here.

Comment: Take the solution from previous question. At the start - execute the query which gets columns names and sums (use JSON_TABLE function for unpivotting) and combines column names into one CSV in the ordering which you need in final output. then add `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME, @generated_csv_columnlist)` clause into `GROUP_CONCAT` - this will sort the columns in output in the ordering which you need.

Comment: Wow! I am interested on this solution. Let me work this out and if you don't mind I will get back to you if I face come difficulty? Perhaps, tomorrow early morning I will work on this.